# Trigger.IO how to find out device type with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, trigger.io

I'm currently developing a mobile app using Trigger.io. Since i only have one code for all platforms and devices, I need to get the device type (i.e Android v4.3, iOS 7). is there any built-in function for that? like `forge.device` or something like that? or should i rely on `navigator.userAgent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was just a plugin released last week I think, will give you device and version

https://trigger.io/modules/platform/current/